# Find the folder in which a lotus notes document is present

Tags: lotus-domino

I am accessing lotus notes using DIIOP. I am trying to find the folder in which a email is present. I have Unid of the email to find the folder.

Enabling folder references is not an option for me, because I will be working on a production system which is running for years.

Is there any way I can find a the folder unid/name in which a mail is present using DIIOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Torsten's answer is correct, but it would really be ridiculously inefficient to do it for a lot of documents, one document at a time - and especially over IIOP.

If you're doing it for lots of documents, I would add them all to a NotesNoteCollection object. Then for each folder I would build another  NotesNoteCollection object and use the Intersect method to find all the documents in common to both collections, then move to the next folder, etc.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for the answer.

Is there any possibility to read the parent of a document from any index table in low level C API?

Comment: Not without folder references. And please note: a document can be in many folders, and I'm not talking about copies of document - which is what some other systems allow. In the Notes/Domino environment one document's noteid can be referenced by many folders. There isn't really a concept of "the parent".

Comment: Yes you are correct, I have seen Java and Lotus Script code to place same document in multiple  folders.

Is this applicable for Email application to have same email in multiple folders? I could not find any menu/action to copy the item to a folder

Comment: In the action bar there is a folder- menu with an action "Move to folder". in the dialog that opens you can chose to "move" or "add" the document to the folder. In second case the document will be in the "source" folder as well as in the target folder.

Comment: You can also simply drag and drop a message to multiple folders. This doesn't work if your starting place is a folder because the drag drop removes the message from the source folder, but if your starting place is the All Documents the message is added to the folder but it stays in the view, so you can add it to another folder, and another...

Comment: Is there any way to get a NoteCollection object containing all the emails present in a single view?

There is no method to get document  collection from a NoteView object.
NoteCollection accepts a Formula but I could not find a way to mention the view name in Formula.

Comment: There is a view selection formula that tyou can find by examining the view in Domino Designer. Use that same formula. If you need to get the formula programmatically, yes,there's no easy documented way, but it can be done. You would build another NoteCollection object with selectViews, iterate through the view notes and examine the $TITLE item to find the view that you are interested in, and then read the formula from the $Formula item.

Comment: I just noticed that the question in your last comment actually seems only marginally related to the question of finding the folders that a document is in. I'm guessing that the relationship is that you have been tasked with finding not just the folders, but the views as well - but views are not folders, obviously. Next time, please open up a new question instead of introducing new topics in the comment thread. If you tag it with lotus-domino, lotus-domino, lotusscript, etc., I will definitely see it, as will others who can help.

Answer (score 2):

Without folder references the document does NOT have the information about the folder in which is resided.

The only possibility is to go through all folders and check, if the document is in the allentries- collection.

Code could look somehow like this (I am not good in Java, so this is LotusScript- Code, but Java will use the same methods / classes):

```vb
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim doc as NotesDocument

Set db = ... database that you work on
Set doc = .... document that you work on

Dim fc As NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim fe As NotesViewEntry
ForAll f In db.AllViews
    If f.IsFolder Then
        Set fc = f.AllEntries '- get all entries in folder
        Set fe = fc.GetEntry( doc ) '- try to get object for doc from folder
        If not fe is Nothing then
           '- This document is in this folder... remember foldername, do whatever....
        End If
    End If
End ForAll
```

Comment: Hi Torsten, Thanks for the answer. Iterating through all the documents will have severe performance impact for my application.